# How can you select which card deck to use in a Clash Royale battle?

Tags: clash-royale

I've got 3 battle decks I can customize, but when you start a battle you we always seem to be using deck 1. How can you select a different deck? Will this unlock at a specific arena? If you cannot, what is the use of the other decks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see numbers <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> and the active deck is differentiated with a different color. Just touch any number whose deck you want to use.

Then, just battle on. That is it. A touch on one of those 3 numbers activates that deck. Then you're ready to go battle with that deck.